# Conditional Regex Replace in C# without MatchEvaluator

Tags: c#, regex

So, Im trying to make a program to rename some files. For the most part, I want them to look like this,

[Testing]StupidName - 2[720p].mkv

But, I would like to be able to change the format, if so desired. If I use MatchEvaluators, you would have to recompile every time. Thats why I don't want to use the MatchEvaluator.

The problem I have is that I don't know how, or if its possible, to tell Replace that if a group was found, include this string. The only syntax for this I have ever seen was something like `(?<group>:data)`, but I can't get this to work. Well if anyone has an idea, im all for it.

EDIT:

Current Capture Regexes =

```
^(\[(?<FanSub>[^\]\)\}]+)\])?[. _]*(?<SeriesTitle>[\w. ]*?)[. _]*\-[. _]*(?<EpisodeNumber>\d+)[. _]*(\-[. _]*(?<EpisodeName>[\w. ]*?)[. _]*)?([\[\(\{](?<MiscInfo>[^\]\)\}]*)[\]\)\}][. _]*)*[\w. ]*(?<Extension>\.[a-zA-Z]+)$

^(?<SeriesTitle>[\w. ]*?)[. _]*[Ss](?<SeasonNumber>\d+)[Ee](?<EpisodeNumber>\d+).*?(?<Extension>\.[a-zA-Z]+)$    

^(?<SeriesTitle>[\w. ]*?)[. _]*(?<SeasonNumber>\d)(?<EpisodeNumber>\d{2}).*?(?<Extension>\.[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

Current Replace Regex = `[${FanSub}]${SeriesTitle} - ${EpisodeNumber} [${MiscInfo}]${Extension}`

Using Regex.Replace, the file `TestFile 101.mkv`, I get `[]TestFile - 1[].mkv`. What I want to do is make it so that `[]` is only included if the group `FanSub` or `MiscInfo` was found.

I can solve this with a MatchEvaluator because I actually get to compile a function. But this would not be a easy solution for users of the program. The only other idea I have to solve this is to actually make my own Regex.Replace function that accepts special syntax.

Comment: your question isn't very clear... please explain what you want with more details, and post your code that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be able to specify an arbitrary format dynamically rather than hard-code it into your code.

Perhaps one solution is to break your filename parts into specific groups then pass in a replacement pattern that takes advantage of those group names. This would give you the ability to pass in different replacement patterns which return the desired filename structure using the [Regex.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx).

Since you didn't explain the categories of your filename I came up with some random groups to demonstrate. Here's a quick example:

```
string input = "Testing StupidName Number2 720p.mkv";
string pattern = @"^(?<Category>\w+)\s+(?<Name>.+?)\s+Number(?<Number>\d+)\s+(?<Resolution>\d+p)(?<Extension>\.mkv)$";

string[] replacePatterns =
{
    "[${Category}]${Name} - ${Number}[${Resolution}]${Extension}",
    "${Category} - ${Name} - ${Number} - ${Resolution}${Extension}",
    "(${Number}) - [${Resolution}] ${Name} [${Category}]${Extension}"
};

foreach (string replacePattern in replacePatterns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacePattern));
}
```

As shown in the sample, named groups in the pattern, specified as `(?<Name>pattern)`, are referred to in the replacement pattern by `${Name}`.

With this approach you would need to know the group names beforehand and pass these in to rearrange the pattern as needed.

Comment: This is what i have currently done, with diffrent group names. Using '(${Number}) - [${Resolution}] ${Name} [${Category}]${Extension}' as an example. Lets say we dont find ${Resolution}, how can i make it so the regex replace wont include the "[" or "]". If I dont deal with that, I get '(1) - [] Name [720p].mkv' and that stupid empty space is my problem.

Comment: @Buttink that's not supported in `Regex.Replace` out of the box. One option is to check each group for a value then build up the pattern as needed, but you lose the flexibility of passing in different patterns (ie. you would be limited to 1 pattern). Another option is to check the groups and parse the *replacement pattern* to remove the missing groups from it. This is likely going to be error prone if the patterns are up to the users.

Comment: .. poo >.> Technically you answered my question :)